# Mongoose find() not returning all parts of document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, next-auth

I am trying to retrieve user information from a MongoDB database, and whenever I use find() the return value is empty.  To make it weirder, findOne returns an object with only the 'email' property.  I have wasted too much time here please help xD.  I'm also using Next.js with next-auth

[...nextauth].js

```
...
async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          await dbConnect();

          const user = await User.find({}).exec();

          return user;
...
```

Mongoose Schema
User.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema ({
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    roles: [{
      type: String
    }],
  }, {
    collection: 'users',
    timestamps: true
  }
);
userSchema.index({ email: 1 }, { unique: true});

const User = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
export default User;
```

and yeah, if I use findOne instead of find, I get an object with only the email property

Recreated collection
Schema.add in User.js
Projection with find()

Comment: I guess that you have an object with only the email property in the database